# bootstrap datepicker show default date selected

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Im using bootstrap datepicker and I'm [applying the set date function](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html).

ie.,

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2011, 2, 5));
```

This works fine but the date specified is not getting selected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After selecting the date using **`setDate`** method, you need to update the `datepicker` in order to get the selected date in `datepicker`.

**Before:**

[image]

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2011, 2, 5));
$('#datepicker').datepicker('update');  //update the bootstrap datepicker
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtzSd/)

**Finally:**

[image]

Comment: Shame there isn't a option to do this rather that using the API.

Answer (score 1):

Im using bootstrap datepicker. below code worked for me:

```
$('#my-datepicker').datepicker('setDate', 'now');
```